# Changing implicit value in scala response of nested object

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit-conversion

I have a controller

```
def getCars(notation: Option[Boolean] = Some(false)) = identified.auth(hasOceanScope).async { implicit request =>
  carService.getCars().map {
    case Seq() => Response.NotFound
    case cars => Response.Ok(cars)
  }
}
```

Car case class looks like this:

```
case class Car(
  name: String,
  createdAt: LocalDateTimeOffset,
  wheels: Seq[Wheel]
)

object Car{
  implicit val wheelFormat = Wheel.format
  implicit def toOffset(date: LocalDateTime): LocalDateTimeOffset = LocalDateTimeOffset.apply(date)

  implicit val format = Json.format[Car]



case class Wheel(
  name: String,
  createdAt: LocalDateTimeOffset
)

object Wheel{
  implicit val format = Json.format[Wheel]
  implicit def toOffset(date: LocalDateTime): LocalDateTimeWithOffset = LocalDateTimeWithOffset.apply(date)
 )
```

When notation query parameter is true -> want to return createdAt Car object and Wheel object field with notation => 2022-10-22T00:00:00#1
When notation query parameter is false -> want to return createdAt Car object and Wheel object field without notation => 2022-10-22T00:00:00

That is why I have create two formats in LocalDateTimeOffset object

```
case class LocalDateTimeWithOffset(dt: LocalDateTime, offset: Int) {

  val localDateTimeWithOffsetReads: Reads[LocalDateTimeWithOffset] = Reads.of[String].flatMap {
    str => if (str.contains("#")) {
      val (dt, offset) = str.splitAt(str.indexOf("#"))
      Reads.pure(LocalDateTimeWithOffset(LocalDateTime.parse(dt), offset.drop(1).toInt))
    } else {
      Reads.pure(LocalDateTimeWithOffset(LocalDateTime.parse(str), 1))
    }
  }

  val localDateTimeWithOffsetWrites: Writes[LocalDateTimeWithOffset] = new Writes[LocalDateTimeWithOffset] {
    override def writes(a: LocalDateTimeWithOffset): JsValue = JsString(a.dt.format(dateTimeUTCFormatter) + s"#${a.offset}")
  }

  val localDateTimeWithOffsetWritesOff: Writes[LocalDateTimeWithOffset] = new Writes[LocalDateTimeWithOffset] {
    override def writes(a: LocalDateTimeWithOffset): JsValue = JsString(a.dt.format(dateTimeUTCFormatter))
  }

  val localDateTimeWithoutOffsetFormat: Format[LocalDateTimeWithOffset] = Format(localDateTimeWithOffsetReads, localDateTimeWithOffsetWritesOff)
  val localDateTimeWithOffsetFormat: Format[LocalDateTimeWithOffset] = Format(localDateTimeWithOffsetReads, localDateTimeWithOffsetWrites)

  implicit var format: Format[LocalDateTimeWithOffset] = localDateTimeWithoutOffsetFormat
}
```

But how can I use two different formats from controller based on notation query parameter value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well just looking at your question's title, `changing implicit value` is not something you would see Scala developers do, because compiler is responsible to lookup for implicit values, and you would definitely want to avoid `ambiguous implicits found` error. instead, you see developers using something so called `type class instance constructor` or something similar. This is how it works **in your case**:

Assuming you have a class `A`, which can be formatted to/from Json in many ways:

```scala
case class A(field1: String) // could have more fields

object A {
  val formatFirstApproach: Format[A] = ???
  val formatSecondApproach: Format[A] = ???
  // note that the above instances are not implicit
  def getFormat(somePredicate: Boolean): Format[A] = {
  // input parameters can be anything, these are the parameters you need,
  // in order to be able to decide which instance to return
  if (somePredicate) formatFirstApproach else formatSecondApproach
  }
}
```

And then, given a class `B` which has an instance variable of type `A` in it, you can use the `type class instance constructor`:

```scala
case class B(a: A, field2: Int)

object B {
  // this is the type class instance constructor, since it constructs an instance of a type class (Format in this case)
  implicit def format(implicit aFormatter: Format[A]): Format[B] = Json.format
}
```

And the thing is, you probably would not care about the serialization unless in the controller layer, so in the controller layer you can do:

```scala
def someApi(flag: Boolean) = Action async { req => 
  implicit val aFormatter = A.getFormat(flag) // that's it, you don't need to mention anything more anywhere
  businessLogic().map {
    case Seq() => Response.NotFound
    case cars => Response.Ok(Json.toJson(cars))
  }
}
```